# Is it safe to remove chess.app

Tags: applications, macos, system-requirements

I was cleaning my MBP out the other day and found `chess.app` in my `/applications` folder. I tried deleting it and Yosemite gave me this error:
[image]

Is this safe to delete? I was able to delete the `DVD Player` application just fine. So why can't I delete `chess.app`? Does this have some system files hidden inside it? Could I simply delete it by doing `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Chess.app`? If it is safe to delete then why doesn't it let you do it by finder? I mean how many people who use OS X use `chess.app`?

Comment: Removing the chess app is like renaming a ship. You just do not do this. Chess has been there at least since OS 7

Comment: What would be gained by removing it? 7.2 MB… you'd have to be in serious need of a bigger drive for that to be vaguely important

Comment: @Tetsujin I just don't want junk applications. Thats why. I never play chess (don't know how to) and hardly ever play games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deleted **Chess.app** from every version of Mac OS X and OS X that I've used starting with Mac OS X 10.4.x and have never had an issue from doing so.

You can use [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to do it, although you first need to uncheck **[] Protect default apps** in its General Preferences.

Note:  To all that have commented about not removing Chess.app, it is for each User to decide whether or not one wants to keep an app that is of no use to them and will have absolutely no side effect whatsoever in removing it, providing it's done in a safe manner.